Difficult issue with Bluetooth
This must be an RPi issue because after an hour of searching, I've found nothing similar:
I have an RPi3A and an RPi4B sitting about 2 meters apart. Both are running an up-to-date bullseye RPi OS "Lite". I want to connect them via Bluetooth, but I'm having a problem: Both units report the other is not available.
Here's what I'm seeing on the RPi3A:
bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller B8:27:E2:F3:8A:58 Pairable: yes 
power on
Changing power on succeeded

And here on the RPi4B:
bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller DC:A6:3E:02:F0:97 Pairable: yes
power on
Changing power on succeeded

And so I set to pair one with the other. I chose to pair the 3A to the 4B:
bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller DC:A6:3E:02:F0:97 Pairable: yes
power on
Changing power on succeeded
pair B8:27:E2:F3:8A:58
Device B8:27:E2:F3:8A:58 not available  # this response comes with NO HESITATION
<repeat many times w/same result>

I've switched and tried pairing the 4B to the 3A. I get the same result: Device XXX not available. Pretty frustrating because I can see that it is available... but what I see is not important I guess - only what bluetoothctl sees.
I've checked rfkill on both Pi3A:
rfkill --output-all
ID TYPE      DEVICE TYPE-DESC         SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   Wireless LAN unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   Bluetooth    unblocked unblocked

and the 4B:
rfkill --output-all
ID TYPE      DEVICE TYPE-DESC         SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   Wireless LAN unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   Bluetooth    unblocked unblocked

I don't know what else to check, and I don't know what I'm missing. Can anyone help?

Edit: Progress?
After waiting a very long time, I happened to look at my SSH terminal for the RPi4B during a scan on operation in bluetoothctl.  I saw the MAC for the RPi3B in the list! The outcome of that was that I've got the RPi3A paired with the RPi4B and vice-versa.
Unfortunately, all attempts to connect to one from the other always fail immediately after being initiated. I watch this happen through the btmon app. It always happens that the final items logged say, "Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)". WTFO?
$ sudo btmon -T

...

> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                      #25 [hci0] 2024-04-04 06:00:45.742950
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 12
        Count: 2
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                              #26 [hci0] 2024-04-04 06:00:47.899753
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 12
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                      {0x0001} [hci0] 2024-04-04 06:00:47.899807
        BR/EDR Address: DC:A6:3E:02:F0:97 (Raspberry Pi Trading Ltd)
        Reason: Connection terminated by remote host (0x03)

And I wonder if this ⤵︎ might have something to do with my problems?? ~ # note the last 3 lines
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-04-04 22:23:37 UTC; 2min 53s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 507 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 407)
        CPU: 93ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─507 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a bluetoothd[507]: Bluetooth daemon 5.55
Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a bluetoothd[507]: Starting SDP server
Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a bluetoothd[507]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a bluetoothd[507]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a bluetoothd[507]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Apr 04 22:23:37 rpi3a bluetoothd[507]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)


Ensure that the Bluetooth firmware and drivers are up-to-date on both Raspberry Pis.

@liaifat85: I run apt updates & upgrades frequently, incl.  earlier in the. day today. I don't think that's the problem - unless the updates you're. speaking of are not included with apt??

Have you tried doing a scan on before doing the pair B8:27:E2:F3:8A:58?

@ukBaz: Yes, always. And the odd thing is that (on both Pis) the scan never shows the MAC of the the other Pi. Yet, there are other MACs that do show up in the scan. BTW - do you have a couple of Pis to test this on?

shouldn't you also do discoverable on?

@JaromandaX: Yes, yes - done that. It times out after a while & has to be refreshed, but yes. bluetoothctl keeps you informed.

A situation where the  "connect and then disconnect" behaviour is seen is when the two devices don't have complimentary services available. This results in the device connecting, sees what services are available, and then disconnects because there is nothing it is looking for. What is it you want to do once the two devices are connected?

Run show on bluetoothctl and you need to see a serial RFCOMM service with a UUID of 0000-1101-... There will not be one. Back in my day you had to run "sdptool add SP" before bluetoothctl to add a serial service, but this no longer works. This answer looks  most relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53069598/bluez-adding-services-attributes-and-profiles-without-sdptool-command

@ukBaz: Good question... I haven't actually worked that out in any detail; I couldn't get music to play, so I thought I'd try to set up a Pi-to-Pi BT connection to exchange "data"... I had short textual messages in mind for "data". But the message exchange could be useful... I guess that has something to do w/ the BT "profile"? Any ideas toward a solution appreciated!

@petzval: AIUI, the show cmd under bluetoothctl gives information on the controller. But you're correct - the show listing mentions nothing re an RFCOMM service. I did read something about that last night & intended to try it today. I've read that sdptool is deprecated, but I checked & is still available on both bullseye systems I'm using. The link you provided looks promising... but what are you suggesting I try exactly?

You need an RFCOMM serial service for data, but an audio service if you really want music, and I can't help with that.

@petzval: Yes - I've gathered that - but that division makes little sense to me. Data is data... It's not clear to me why must there be two "transport mechanisms".

The value you are seeing in the Bluetooth status is nothing to worry about. There are various posts around on how to fix it, but it is a red-herring for your issue. The protocols listed on the controller are telling the other devices what protocols it can support. Those protocols are high in the stack and as a result are expecting the data to be formatted in a certain way. If there is no protocol that knows how to unpack the data it is sending then it it disconnects.

I suspect that the audio isn't working because you have installed the RPi OS "Lite" version. I'm sure it is present in the full-fat version. You've seen the option to use bluedot but you don't want to use Python. How do you want to send the data from one RPi to another?

@ukBaz: Yes, I am rather attached to the 'Lite' distro - using X/Wayland on these tiny RPis reminds me of the old Westerns where this huge fat guy mounts a little quarter horse - I just can't bear to watch. :)  "How do you want to send the data from one RPi to another?" Well - it seems only the deprecated options are left; i.e. rfcomm? I don't understand why - if rfcomm is deprecated - there has been nothing except Python libraries to replace it.
